# VSCode split header files to the right automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click on a header file on the explorer, I want the header files to be on the right split of the editor automatically regardless of where I'm currently focused on the editor while the .cpp/.c files stay on the left side when I click on them.

Normally, when I click on a file on the explorer, regardless of the type of the file it opens it on the currently focused split. As someone who is used to working with 2 splits this can be really annoying on large projects.

How can I achieve this? Are there extensions for this? Or can I create something like a macro?

Comment: This post would be clearer with a screenshot.... (I think)

Comment: Would be easier to upload a video. Can I upload videos?

Comment: [Is it possible to embed videos in questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248249/is-it-possible-to-embed-videos-in-questions) (Which says that it's not possible (read "advised") on stackoverflow.

Comment: and [Animated gifs'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348733/animated-gifs-in-answers) is a no-go too 

Comment: you can try to create an extension that adds a button to the explorer tree items (add menu entry), when clicked on this button check the file URL and open the file in the correct view column

Comment: @rioV8 I guess that's my only option... so much work for such a simple task, just wanted to ask in case there is an alternative that I'm not seeing...